# Is Blackbeard afraid of Luffy?

Tags: one-piece

Why does Blackbeard send Burgess to assassinate Luffy? Is he afraid of him?
I mean with his 2 Devil Fruit powers, he is overpowered.
Even just with his Yami Yami no Mi, he won quite easily against Ace, and now he also has the Gura Gura no Mi and a strong crew.

So is there a special reason for him to kill Luffy? And why not do it himself? Does he fear the D in Luffy's name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blackbeard did not send Burgess to kill Luffy, he did not even know Luffy was at Dressrosa to begin with. **Blackbeard originally had send out Burgess to Dressrosa to get the Fire Fruit**. Later it was Sabo who ate the Fire Fruit, but it looks like not much people knew about this. The only thing most people really knew, was that *Lucy* had eaten the Fire Fruit.

[image: enter image description here!]

Later when Sabo blew up the colosseum, Burgess realized that *Lucy* was not Luffy any more, because Luffy already ate a Devil Fruit before and could not eat a second. He just did not know who actually ate the fruit and thought that person would have been long gone by now. That's why he went for the next best thing, not having to go home empty handed. Though, when Sabo showed Burgess, that he had eaten the Fire Fruit, Burgess completely forgot about Luffy and turned his attacks towards Sabo instead, still hoping to get the Fire Fruit eventually.

[image: enter image description here!]

On a side note: Blackbeard never targeted Luffy for personal reasons. He originally wanted to kill Luffy to make a name for himself, but after he became a Warlord, he did not care much for Luffy any more. He could have easily destroyed Luffy at Impel Down, but he had other ambitions by that time, other than the one he had at Mocktown, Jaya.

Comment: oh really i didn't recognize that. Burgess was also in the tournament right?
i have to read it again. But then Burgess should take Doflas fruit... thinks is more powerful. Or Law couldn't even move. strange...

Comment: @BBallBoy when luffy released conquerors haki during his fight with Don chinjao Burgess got curious and replied "its getting interesting" when he heard it was Luffy. He later told BB on the snailphone. BB said that he was happy Ace would be joining his crew in the form of the fruit. He didnt have any intention of going after Luffy.

Comment: yeah you were right, he was after Ace devil fruit. So he must carry a fruit with him, otherwise he couldn't get luffys power...
but i'm still confused, he could easily go after sabo and try to kill him, because this was his mission, to get Aces power.

Comment: @BBallBoy I updated the answer with the reveals from today's chapter. It looks like he indeed could have gone for Sabo, he just didn't realize Sabo was Lucy. Now that he does, he indeed goes after Sabo.

Comment: oh nice, the new chapter is out! :D thanks for your effort :)

Answer (score 3):

At the moment I reckon this is all just speculation. I think he wants to kill Luffy because of his ability to inspire the people around him, as often noted by Kuzan.

At the battle of Marineford Luffy continuously inspired the other pirates to rise up and fight, just by being himself. This alone is a force to be reckoned with that could well be used against Blackbeard.

I personally think that he doesn't see luffy worthy enough to be have his personal attention when it comes to the assassination. It's almost the same as Luffy not bothering with alot of minor henchman of the bad guys he encounters. Often the crew just take care of those.

As for the fear of the D in Luffy's name concerned. I highly doubt thats the case, since (spoiler alert)

> Blackbeard is a D. aswell, Marshall D. Teach

Time will tell what Oda has in store for us tho

Comment: yes i now this about Blackbeard, but if he knows about the legend of the "D" and he could kill Luffy, there is one D fewer in his way to get Piratking.